# prevent Outlook from repeating "RE:" or "Trả lời:" (vietnamese) when reply email

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

Sometimes some of our colleagues got a problem that make the email subject get longer and longer by repeating `RE:` or `Trả lời:` like in the image (`RE:` label in Vietnamese) 
How could I stop that?

[image: Outlook got repeating reply label]

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a internationalization bug in Outlook.

Outlook is programmed to remove any prefix containing 3 or less alpha characters,
followed by a colon (RE:, FWD:, NET: etc).
So, under normal conditions, Outlook will strip any prefix.

In your case, apparently the translator to Vietnamese made the mistake of
translating `RE` as `Trả lời`, a mistake that breaks this convention.

You may report this as a bug to Microsoft. There isn't much more that you can do.

It’s best to stick with RE and FW as a courtesy to other people.
Outlook lets non-English language users do that with two settings found
in *File > Options > Advanced > International options*:

- Use English for message flag labels
- Use English for message headers on replies and forwards and for forward notifications